# Communicating with Arduino Uno and Android nexus 5

Tags: android, serial-port, arduino

I'm new to android app. I want to read data from my arduino Uno R3 and display it on my app using a serial cable and an OTG adapter.

Although, I can't get my UsbManager to recognized my device. So when I try to set up a connection, it always fail. 
Here's the part of my code where I initiate everything.

```
public UsbManager = mUsbManager; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_depth);
    setupActionBar();   
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          textView.setText("Bravo");
          updateDevice();
          if (mRunning == true)  {
             receiveThread();
          }
     }
    });
}


public void updateDevice() {
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    if (device != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Initialisation 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        initDevice(device);
    }

    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Initialisation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        initDevice(device);
    } else {
        initDevice(null);
    }


}
(...) //Obviously, this is not in my code!! 

 private boolean initDevice(UsbDevice device) {

        mConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);

        if (mConnection == null) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "Opening USB device failed!");
            Toast.makeText(DisplayDepth.this, "open failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
```

And it always fail here ( I get the toast msg "open failed" ). 
I add to my manifest what it takes so my arduino r3 is recognized and a connection message is always shown when I plug it into my phone.... Need help!!! 
Thanks

Comment: this will help you http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549

Comment: Do you have a host-capable phone and an OTG adapter cable with the detect pin grounded?